# How can I lock the rotation on an android device programmatically (not device-wide, just my app)?

Tags: android, rotation, orientation

I know how to change the orientation in the manifest.xml:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.mygdx.game.android.AndroidLauncher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
  >>    android:screenOrientation="landscape"   <<   here
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
```

And I know how to set it in java:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Allright, but what if I want to COMBINE `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`and `android:screenOrientation="locked"`? The only answers that I found show either the first or the second, but not how to do both.
I want my app to always start in landscape and NEVER rotate or flip.
If I use "landscape" it can still be flipped upside down, so it's either 90 deg or 270 deg.
If I use "locked", it won't rotate BUT will stay at 0 degrees in portrait mode.

Is it even possible to combine both behaviours? Just like if I go into the settings and disable auto-rotation on my device. That's what I want for as long my app is running.

Comment: I always thought that `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE` locked the orientation to one configuration, and `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE` allowed for a 180 degree rotation.

Comment: @danBuonocore I don't know I'm completely new to android development. According to the documentation that's what it is supposed to do, I guess, but it doesn't work for me. It still flips upside down when I tilt the screen in SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE mode. Edit: Just tested it again. When I start the app holding the device sideways, it works, but If I start the app holding it upright it keeps flipping if I tilt it.

Comment: So when you hold it in portrait, it moves to landscape and allows you to flip to the other landscape, but if you hold it in landscape then everything works?

Comment: Exactly. If I start the app while holding my device in landscape mode, it works, if I start it while holding it in portrait mode, it switches to landscape like it should, but then can be flipped upside down.